# Docker tunnel traffic on specific port via VPN

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, iptables

Not sure if this is docker specific or a general networking question.

I'm running a Debian Jessie server with serveral docker containers.  My understanding is that docker creates a virtual interface (or strictly speaking a virtual ethernet bridge) called `docker0` and binds the virtual interfaces of each individual container.  It then manipulates the host's `iptables` to allow communication between each container's exposed ports and the host's network.

I have a VPN, the interface is `tun0`.  One of the containers exposes two ports: `8888` and `23456`.  I want to tunnel all traffic **to and from** port `23456` through the VPN.

**How can this be done?**

Another way of looking at this is that docker automatically routes traffic based on the port to the right container.  I want to insert another layer via `iptables`, where traffic on port `23456` is directed to the VPN and any traffic from the VPN is directed to port `23456`.

For info, the VPN provider uses OpenVPN.

Answer (score 0):

This should be completely automatic, except for the need of the usual masquerade rule:

```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i docker0 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Just for the sake of thoroughness, make sure you have the routing rule, on the host, servicing docker0: if you can ping the dockers from the host, no need to read further. Otherwise add

```
  ip route add Docker'sNetwork/16 via dev docker0
```